# Using SQL query to search most viewed entry

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL database. I'm trying to make a query where I can get the most viewed ArticleID in my table.

ArticleView TABLE:

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
| ArticleViewNum | ArticleID |     ViewDateTime    |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        1       |     2     | 2013-12-01 10:14:00 |
|        2       |     2     | 2012-15-02 12:14:00 |
|        3       |     3     | 2012-16-04 14:01:00 |
|        4       |     4     | 2012-23-06 09:30:00 |
|        5       |     1     | 2012-30-06 01:27:00 |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Following query will give you the most viewed articles and their viewed count.

```
select TOP 10 ArticleID, count(*) As ViewCount 
from ArticleView Group By ArticleID Order By ViewCount Desc;
```